# Jquery slider not working for unknown reasons

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm trying to use a jquery slider that I've used many times before - but this time it isn't working and I can't figure out why.

Here is the HTML Code, basically just a main slider div with another div inside for the slides and each slide div has a class of slide (sorry to ramble, I can't post this without 'more explanation'):

```
<div id="slider">
<div id="slides">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="images/portfolio/web1.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="images/portfolio/web5.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
</div>
    <img src="images/arrow-L.png" alt="Left" id="slider-arrow-left"/>
    <img src="images/arrow-R.png" alt="Right" id="slider-arrow-right"/>
</div>
```

And the CSS, just setting heights and widths:

```
#slider{height: 200px; position: relative; z-index: 1;}
#slider #slides {height: 200px; width: 883px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;}
#slider #slides .slide{height: 200px; width: 883px;}
#slider img#slider-arrow-left {position: absolute; left: -30px; top: 80px; cursor: pointer;   z-index: 999;}
#slider img#slider-arrow-right{position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 80px; cursor: pointer; z-index: 999;}
```

And the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $('#slides').cycle({ 
        fx:      'scrollHorz', 
        speed:  'slow', 
        timeout: 10000, 
        pause:   1,
        prev: $('#slider-arrow-left'),
        next: $('#slider-arrow-right'),
        cssBefore:{ 
            top: 0,
            opacity: 1,
            display: 'block'
        }, 
        animOut: {  
            top: 360
        },
        before: function(curr, next, opts){
            var $curr = $(curr);
            var $next = $(next);
        },
        pause: 1,
        pager: '#slider-controls',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (idx, slide) {
            return '#slider-controls li:eq(' + idx + ') a';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what slider plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm not using a plugin, just the above script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried your example using [jQuery cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). and it seems fine,

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#slides').cycle({ 
        fx:      'scrollHorz', 
        speed:  'slow', 
        timeout: 0, //prevents auto start of jquery cycle.
        pause:   1,
        prev: $('#slider-arrow-left'),
        next: $('#slider-arrow-right'),
        cssBefore:{ 
            top: 0,
            opacity: 1,
            display: 'block'
        }, 
        animOut: {  
            top: 360
        },
        before: function(curr, next, opts){
            var $curr = $(curr);
            var $next = $(next);
        },
        pause: 1,
        pager: '#slider-controls',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (idx, slide) {
            return '#slider-controls li:eq(' + idx + ') a';
        }
    });

});​
```

Here :

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TPeGv/1/)

you may tweak it accordingly.

Comment: Glad to be of service, please mark the answer as solved if it helped you.

Comment: Just one more quick question. Is there a way to prevent it from starting automatically? I'm using it on a portfolio page that will have multiple sliders, I don't want them to run on their own.

Comment: simple, just set the timeout option to '0', i have edited the code above.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure you can tell I'm very new at this! I will mark the question as answered